# Are there any simpler transformations for the elliptic integral of the second kind $\text E(z,m)$ than these?

Tags: reference-request, notation, transformation, online-resources, elliptic-integrals

$\def\F\{\operatorname F}\def\E{\operatorname E}$

[Elliptic F$(x,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/17/01/) appears in [elliptic E$(x,m) =\int_0^x\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(x)}dx$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/16/) [parameter $m$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parameter.html) transformations. Luckily the DLMF has [reciprocal/imaginary modulus transformations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7) and [Gauss/Landen transformations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.8), but these both use $\E(x,k)= \int_0^x\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)} dx$. The following formulas work around $z=0$:

Reciprocal parameter transformation:

$$\E(z,m)=\sqrt m\E\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt m\sin(z)\right),\frac1m\right)+\frac{1-m}{\sqrt m}\F\left(\sin^{-1}(\sqrt m\sin(z),\frac1m\right)\tag1$$

Complementary parameter/imaginary argument transformation:

$$\E(z,m)=i\E(i\tanh^{-1}(\sin(z)),1-m)-i\F(i\tanh^{-1}(\sin(z)),1-m)+\sin(z)\sqrt{\frac{1-m\sin^2(z)}{\cos^2(z)}}$$

Negative parameter transform from [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326579989_New_variable_transformation_of_elliptic_integrals) using [Elliptic $\E(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticE%28z%29) and [complex conjugate $\bar z$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=conjugate%28z%29)

$$\E(z,m)\mathop=^{m<1}\sqrt{1-m}\left(\E\left(\frac m{1-m}\right)-\E\left(\frac\pi 2-z,\frac m{1-m}\right)\right)\mathop=^{m>1}-\overline{\sqrt{1-m}\left(\E\left(\frac m{1-m}\right)-\E\left(\frac\pi 2-z,\frac m{1-m}\right)\right)}\tag2$$

Ascending Landen transformation:

$$\E(z,m)=(1+\sqrt m)\E\left(\frac12(\sin^{-1}(\sqrt m\sin(z))+z),\frac{2\sqrt m}{m+1}\right)+ (1-\sqrt m)\F\left(\frac12(\sin^{-1}(\sqrt m\sin(z))+z),\frac{2\sqrt m}{m+1}\right)-\sqrt m\sin(z)$$

Descending Landen transformation:

$$\E(z,m)=\frac{\sqrt{1-m}+1}2\E\left(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{1-m}\tan(z))+z,\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-m}-1}{\sqrt{1-m}+1}\right)^2\right)-\sqrt{1-m}\F(z,m)+\frac{m\cos(z)\sin(z)}{2\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(z)}}$$

These formulas answer most of the original question, but they use $\frac{m\cos(z)\sin(z)}{2\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(z)}}$ and other complicated trigonometric expressions.

What are other *simpler* transformations for $\E(z,m)$, perhaps without trigonometric expressions like in $(1),(2)$?

Comment: Do you know what is a nome ?

Comment: generally the update should be in the question itself, unless your self-answer completely answers the question to your satisfaction

Comment: Hi, it could be difficult to find sources that uses Wolfram's notation given all the theory of Elliptic integrals at least since Cayley was written with $k$ instead of $m$ but for some unknown reason Wolfram uses a different notation.

Comment: However, knowing that $m$ is just $k^2$ in the standard notation, we have the following: 

$$ E(\varphi, im) = \int_{0}^{\varphi} \sqrt{1-im\sin^2\varphi} = \int_{0}^{\varphi} \sqrt{1-(\sqrt{im})^2\sin^2\varphi}=\int_{0}^{\varphi} \sqrt{1-(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\sqrt{m})^2\sin^2\varphi}$$

So $k = e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\sqrt{m}$ in the standard notation.

Comment: But note that

$$ k = \sqrt{m}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{2}}$$


This is a *non--purely imaginary  modulus*. All the transoformations in the theory for imaginary modulus are made with purely imaginary modulus. i.e. modulus of the form $i\bar{k}$ with $\bar{k}\in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: @Bertrand87 $k\to-i k$ gives a formula for $\text E(z,k)$ in terms of $\text E\left(z,-\frac{i k}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)$, so there is a formula for $\text E\left(z,\sqrt m e^\frac{\pi i}4\right)$ in terms of $\text E\left(z,\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi i}4}\sqrt m}{\sqrt{1-i m}}\right)$. From there, a formula for $\text E(z,m)$ is possible. Is this right?

Comment: @TymaGaidash the first transformation assumes that $ik$ has a real part equal to zero (ie is purely imaginary) while  $\sqrt{m}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$ does not. We should find a transofrmation for an imaginary modulus that is not purely imaginary, but I does not know one.

Comment: If you only want the equivalent formulas for the imaginary modulus with Wolfram's notation note that if $m = k^2$ 

$$ \int_{0}^{\varphi}  \sqrt{1-(ik)^2\sin \varphi}d\varphi =\int_{0}^{\varphi}  \sqrt{1+k^2\sin \varphi} d\varphi =   \int_{0}^{\varphi} 
 \sqrt{1-(-m)\sin \varphi}d\varphi = E(\varphi,-m) $$

So the transformation of "negative modulus" in Mathematica is equivalent to the transformation of imaginary modulus in the standard notation.

Comment: @Bertrand87 Thanks for the help. The “negative modulus” term helped find a good reference for a significantly simpler transformation. Maybe you know about simpler forms of the other transformations in the question.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer but an extended comment)

Note for example, the following transformation (using Mathematica notation). Suppose that $0<m<1$, then

$$E(\varphi,-m) = \sqrt{1+m}E\left(\varphi,\frac{ m}{m+1}\right)- \frac{m\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)}{\sqrt{1+m\cos^2\varphi}}$$

For convenience put $\displaystyle \varphi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\displaystyle m=\frac{1}{2}$

$$E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right) =\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

So, in Mathematica notation we are transforming a negative modulus to a positive modulus while using the standard notation we are transforming a purely imaginary modulus to a positive one:

$$E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) $$

My advice is to completely ignore the Wolfram's notation for the theory of elliptic integrals and use it only for computation. They also put a warning on this issue in [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).